# How to schedule a periodic task that is immune to system time change using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python's sched module to run a task periodically, and I think I have come across a bug.

I find that it relies on the time of the system on which the python script is run.  For example, let's say that I want to run a task every 5 seconds.  If I forward the system time, the scheduled task will run as expected.  However, if I rewind the system time to, say 1 day, then the next scheduled task will run in 5 seconds + 1 day.

If you run the script below and then change your system time by a few days back, then you can reproduce the issue.  The problem can be reproduced on Linux and Windows.

```
import sched
import time
import threading

period = 5
scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def check_scheduler():
    print time.time()
    scheduler.enter(period, 1, check_scheduler, ())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print time.time()

    scheduler.enter(period, 1, check_scheduler, ())

    thread = threading.Thread(target=scheduler.run)
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
    exit(0)
```

Anyone has any python solution around this problem?

Comment: Alan, that's not a crazy solution because I have actually already tried time.time - 1 year.  Unfortunately that does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the sched documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html#module-sched):

> class sched.scheduler(timefunc, delayfunc)
>
> The scheduler class defines a generic interface to scheduling events. It needs two functions to actually deal with the “outside
>   world” — timefunc should be callable without arguments, and return a
>   number (the “time”, in any units whatsoever). The delayfunc function
>   should be callable with one argument, compatible with the output of
>   timefunc, and should delay that many time units. delayfunc will also
>   be called with the argument 0 after each event is run to allow other
>   threads an opportunity to run in multi-threaded applications.

The problem you have is that your code uses `time.time()` as `timefunc`, whose return value (when called without arguments) is the current system time and is thus affected by re-winding the system clock.

To make your code immune to system time changes you'd need to provide a `timefunc` which doesn't depend on the system time, start/current timestamps, etc.

You can write your own function, for example one returning the number of seconds since your process is started, which you'd have to **actually count** in your code (i.e. don't `compute it` based on timestamp deltas). The `time.clock()` function *might* help, if it's based on CPU time counters, but I'm not sure if that's true or not.

Comment: Looks like time.clock() fixes the issue on Windows, but not on Unix - which isn't surprising based on this [description] (https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.clock).

However, your idea - to use another timefunc to return the time elapsed since the start of the process - is correct.